# AForge.NET stream from PiCamera - AForge.NET don't receiving any bytes

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

I have stream in `mjpeg` urled `http://192.*.*.1:8000/stream.mjpg` 
Im trying to receive it with C# App with `Aforge.Video` namespace.

```
 internal class CameraManager
    {
        private MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream("http://192.*.*.1:8000/stream.mjpg");

        public CameraManager()
        {
            stream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
            stream.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stream.BytesReceived);
            }
        }

        private void video_NewFrame(object sender,
            NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // get new frame
            Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;

            Console.WriteLine(stream.IsRunning);
            Console.WriteLine(bitmap.Height);
            // process the frame
        }

    }
```

I try to receive data, and in future detect faces, motion etc. Now im only receiving "0 bytes".

I used tutorial [From this URL](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/jpeg_video_streams.html) but i can see, that in sample it is `"http://<axis_camera_ip>/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi"`. I can see my camera streaming in url `http://192.*.*.1:8000/stream.mjpg` very clear. I see that my stream has format `mjpg` in sample `.cgi`

What should i do to receive pics/bytes from this .mjpg stream and then manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that i was using `.NET Core Console Application` instead `.Net Core Framework Console Application`. Replacing project to new with **.Net Framework** with my classes and Entities included from .Net Core working now. [Learn more about AForge with .Net Core plans and progress.](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/issues/23)